# Double to uint64_t conversion

Tags: c++, c++17

Following demo program demonstrates some behaviour I don't understand.

```
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

constexpr double bits64 = 18446744073709551616.0; // 2^64

void diff_hash(double diff)
{
    double hash = bits64 / diff;
    
    uint64_t hash_64_1 = hash;
    
    uint64_t hash_64_2 = hash < std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max() ? hash : std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max();
    
    uint64_t hash_64_3 = std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max();
    if(hash < hash_64_3){
        hash_64_3 = hash;
    }
    
    std::cout << "hash_64_1: " << hash_64_1 << ", " << "hash_64_2: " << hash_64_2 << ", " << "hash_64_3: " << hash_64_3 << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    diff_hash(1);
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
hash_64_1: 0, hash_64_2: 0, hash_64_3: 18446744073709551615
```

Questions:

1.) Why is `hash_64_1 == 0`? Event though value that is assigned is clearly max 64 value

2.) Why is `hash_64_2 == 0`? I confirmed that if I change the line to

```
uint64_t hash_64_2 = hash < std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max() ? hash : std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max();
```

the value of `hash_64_2` max 32 value

Link to Wandbox example https://wandbox.org/permlink/HyXRX2CiNgIIpYkQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `18446744073709551616.0 / 1.0` is evaluated as a `double`. Its value is `18446744073709551616.0`, assuming IEEE754. The behaviour on converting this to an *out of range* `uint64_t` is *undefined*. A common manifestation of that undefined behaviour is *wrap-around* to 0. (That's what most folk assume happens, but the behaviour is undefined when converting from an out of range floating point value.)
2. With the expression `hash < std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()`, the right hand side is converted implicitly to a `double`. But that number cannot be represented as a `double`, so it is rounded to the nearest `double`, which is `18446744073709551616.0`. Hence `hash_64_2` is 0 too.

Comment: Detail: With C at least, uint64_t to double,  the out of range/inexact conversion is not certainly rounded, but implementation-defined - although that is common.  I suspect the same with C++.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.) Why is hash_64_1 == 0? Event though value that is assigned is clearly max 64 value

That is actually hardly clear. `hash` is clearly **greater** than max 64 value. The behaviour of converting an unrepresentable (in target type) floating point to integer is undefined.

Comment: I tested ```uint64_t hash_64_1 = bits64;``` and I get compiler error ```prog.cc: In function 'void diff_hash(double)':
prog.cc:12:30: warning: overflow in conversion from 'double' to 'uint64_t' {aka 'long unsigned int'} changes value from '1.8446744073709552e+19' to '18446744073709551615' [-Woverflow]
   12 |         uint64_t hash_64_1 = bits64;
      |                              ^~~~~~```

Comment: How can I know which max double value is convertible to max uint64 value? `18446744073709551616` is max uint64 value, but in the code represented with double.

Comment: @Rostfrei `I get compiler error` That's not an error. It is a warning. `How can I know which max double value is convertible to max uint64 value?` You can use `std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()`. Your third example does the comparison correctly. `18446744073709551616 is max uint64 value` No it isn't.

Comment: I see now that max value of uint64 is actually `0xffffffffffffffff == 18446744073709551615` and not `2^64 == 18446744073709551616` which is the number of combinations including `0`.

Comment: @Rostfrei I think I misunderstood `How can I know which max double value is convertible to max uint64 value?`. I answered assuming you simply wanted to test whether a double is representable. But to find the largest double that is representable, you can use `std::nextafter(std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max(), 0)` .

Answer (score 1):

"is assigned is clearly max 64 value" --> Off-by-one.

The max `uint64_t` value is `18446744073709551615`, not `18446744073709551616`.

Effects seen are due to UB of converting an out of range `double` to `uint64_t`.